# discord python bot returns "(discord username) said: "hello" (general) 'TextChannel' object is not callable" when command entered on discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yLfjMtsV9s) video and was developing a python bot for discord. Everything was going fine. Programming compiled and the bot comes online. However it does not respond to commands.

Nothing happens except there is an output in the console:

rug#5048 is now running!
rugmaster76 said: "hello" (general)
'TextChannel' object is not callable

when I say hello it is supposed to greet me back with the words "Hey there!"

This is my code.

bot.py:

```
import discord
import responses


async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try:
        response = responses.get_response(user_message)
        await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await message.channel(response)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = 'MTEyODExMDc4NDA4MjM1NDIxNg.GLoasi.NN3Yy2kbyDJ4yBGhPloDE3onIEhQU5OpzumtM4'
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.message_content = True
    client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} is now running!')

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        username = str(message.author)
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel)

        print(f'{username} said: "{user_message}" ({channel})')

        if user_message[0] == '?':
            user_message = user_message[1:]
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=True)
        else:
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=False)


    client.run(TOKEN)
```

responses.py

```
import random


def get_response(message: str) -> str:
    p_message = message.lower()

    if p_message == 'hello':
        return 'Hey there!'

    if message == 'roll':
        return str(random.randint(1, 6))

    if p_message == '!help':
        return'`this is a help message that u can modify`'

    return 'i didnt understand what u wrote, try typing "!help."'
```

main.py:

```
import bot

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run_discord_bot()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is raising the exception "object is not callable" because you are using an object as a method

In `else await message.channel(response)` add `.send` like this `else await message.channel.send(response)`

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is on the line `await message.channel(response)`**, you need to switch it to `await message.channel.send(response)` in your case. 
And **never share your TOKEN anywhere**. Please go to developer portal to regenerate a new token for your bot.
And if you followed exactly what that YouTube tutorial tells you to do, then it's better to stop watching that since it is not a good tutorial based on your code snippet.